# Get Facebook messages

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to write custom facebook messaging application. Is this even possible?
Cannot figure out how to access user's messages. 
For example - i logged into my page, i want to retrieve messages from all my friends. I assume that `/me/inbox` will give me required result, but it requires `read_page_mailboxes` which is accessible only after `App Review` procedure. So i even can't test how messages are working, without sending incomplete app/screencast of functionality which is not even exists.

Answer (score 0):

The review that `read_page_mailboxes` permission documentation's states is [**Login Review**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review?locale=en_US), not [App View](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review), according to [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions?locale=en_US#reference-read_page_mailboxes) page.

I'm not sure but i belive that there is no need to submit a facebook review to use the permission when you're running a debug build app.

Take a look at the [Getting started](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started?locale=en_US) page under the *Create a Development Key Hash* session for more information.

I hope I have helped.

Comment: Yeah,  got it. But it's not working, when i use graph methods such as `me/conversations`, `me/inbox` and etc... or page ids i get `Need permission read_mailbox` exception. So there is a question. Is this even possible to get messages/conversation or facebook closed such possibility?